SharePoint File Viewer Web Part Missing More Options (...)
I cannot figure out why the more options (...) is missing in the settings of the File Viewer web part. I've checked the SharePoint Admin settings, etc. I want to use the Connect to source for dynamic document display.


Please refer to the steps in this article: Dynamic preview via file viewer web part in SharePoint

There is a workaround for this;
Select the Embed Web Part, the ellipses (More options (...)) should be visible on the top right. Connect to your desired source (for example: a document library). In the 'Website address or embed code' part you enter this exact code:
Once done so, you can play around with the Section columns a bit to get the best view. I personally use 'One-third right' and set the Embed Web Part on the left (large section) and the Document Library on the right.
Hope this helps!
